# Pushing ViewController Results In Cant Unwrap Optional.None

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an issue in Swift. When I press a cell on my table I do a segue into another ViewController which has a UIWebView and loads a webpage. This works fine. The custom ViewController code looks like this:

```
class ViewController_ShowView : UIViewController
{
var showName: String?
var showUrl: String?
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = showName

    var requestURL = NSURL(string: showUrl)
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
}
```

However, I am trying to load the ViewController from the AppDelegate (when a user clicks on a UILocalNotification) and it crashes on the web view.loadRequest(request) line from above. Here is how I am attempting to call it:

```
var currentShowsViewController = viewController.topViewController as ViewController_CurrentShows
var viewControllerToPush = ViewController_ShowView()
viewControllerToPush.showName = "Test"
viewControllerToPush.showUrl = "http://www.google.com"                       
currentShowsViewController.navigationController.pushViewController(viewControllerToPush, animated: false)
```

This causes a crash with the error Cant Unwrap Optional.None

I am confused why it works from the perform segue method but not this way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem caused by this line of code:

```
var viewControllerToPush = ViewController_ShowView()
```

You should instantiate view controller from its storyboard. Here is how you can do it:

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil);
let viewControllerToPush : ViewController_ShowView 
  = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showViewVC") as ViewController_ShowView;
```

Note that you should also open your storyboard and set the view controller's identifier to `showViewVC`.

**Remarks:**

The exception get thrown because `@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView` does not get initialized. `@IBOutlet`s in Swift are optionals thus you receive `Cant Unwrap Optional.None`.

Comment: Thanks this works, just had to name the storyboard "Main" instead of "MainStoryBoard".

Comment: If I wanted to make this work through code, is there a way to instantiate the UIWebView so that it doesn't cause this problem?

Comment: You need to create and instance of `UIWebView` in `viewDidLoad` method of you view controller and add the UIWebView instance to your view controller's view hierarchy by calling  `self.view.addSubview(webView)`. You also need to set webView frame or auto-layout constraints to make it positioned properly.